# Spring datasources multiple profiles

Tags: java, xml, spring

I want to create profiles for various databases which I can load depending on which one I'm using.

This is my the relevant part of my application-context.xml file:

```
<beans>

        <!-- ...other beans in common profile-->
        <beans profile="dev">
            <bean id="dataSource"
                    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}"/>
                <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
                <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
                <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
            </bean>
            <beans profile="mariadb">
                <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:databases/mariadb.properties"
                        ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
            </beans>
            <beans profile="mysql">
                <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:databases/mysql.properties"
                        ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
            </beans>
            <beans profile="hsql">
                <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:databases/hsql.properties"
                        ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
            </beans>
        </beans>

        <beans profile="production">
            <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="${jndi.name}"/>
        </beans>
```

My dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <import resource="classpath*:profile-context.xml"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
<beans/>
```

and profile-context.xml

```
<beans>
    <beans profile="dev">
        <import resource="application-context.xml"/>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="production">
        <import resource="application-context.xml"/>
    </beans>
<beans/>
```

finally, my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>dev, mysql</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Although this would work lets say with JUnit tests with @ActiveProfile({"dev", "mysql"}) it doesnt work for my Tomcat container.
Am I doing probably doing something wrong in the way I am wrapping application-context in a dev profile in profile-context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring parses the value of `spring.profiles.active` using `StringUtils. commaDelimitedListToStringArray`. This method is *not* very forgiving, and parses your profile string as `{"dev", " mysql"}` – note the space before `mysql`.

Remove the space after the comma from your `param-value` element, and your code should work.